# Why does WinRT limit my unhandled exception messages/stack traces to 512 characters?

Tags: exception, logging, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, unhandled-exception

So I'm trying to test the logging of unhandled exceptions in a C# Windows Store app. I found with particularly large stack traces or exception messages however, I lose critical information to some arbitrary 512 character limit.

So, I have my handler like so:

```
    void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        string tmp = e.Message;
        var x = e.Exception;
    }
```

Of course, due to the exception crossing language boundaries, the exception object provided is next to useless. The only info it carries is that "an exception of type System.Exception occurred". No stack trace or anything. Luckily, there is also the `Message` property though which contains most of the relevant information for logging exceptions.

However, It's limited to 512 characters!? So, here's an example:

Using this: `throw new Exception(new string('c', 480));` I get this as the message:

> System.Exception:
>   cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
>   at App2.A

Notice it's cut off, right at the 512 character boundary. Here is what is looks like with a short exception message

> System.Exception: cccccccccc    at
>   App2.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)

Can someone explain to me why the only useful field given for tracking unhandled errors in your application is for some reason limited to a very small amount of text?!

Comment: Could you just look at the actual `Exception` that was passed rather than only relying on the `Message` property (as it's the `Exception` instance)? If it's an `exception` you're creating, you could add additional properties as well.

Comment: @wiredprairie the exception that gets passed in is not the exception thrown. The stack trace property is null and the message is useless and generic

Comment: The common answer to questions like this often the obvious one: [because the documentation says so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).